# How to customize css of a specific woocommerce category product?

Tags: css, woocommerce, categories, product

Costumize the css of a specific Product category page

I have found this code:

```php
if ( is_product_category() ) {

  if ( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) ) {
    echo 'Hi! Take a look at our sweet tshirts below.';
  } elseif ( is_product_category( 'games' ) ) {
    echo 'Hi! Hungry for some gaming?';
  } else {
    echo 'Hi! Check our our products below.';
  }

}
```

}

But is not working.

Someone helps?

Comment: that's PHP code you've got there. We'll need to see some HTML in order to help style stuff.

Comment: the html code is the woocommerce archive template. But the question is how can i dinamically change the style of the  product category, you don't need to know th html structure. The plugin that i'm tolking about is woocommerce whom  structure is avaible free online. The difference between product category and category of post in wp is that product category are taxonomies.

Comment: the thing that i'm asking is " in the echo code can i put  <style></style> and  change the css?

Comment: Ah. Well that's a bit different. Probably not best to not do it that way. If I remember correctly, WC will create classes on the body for products/categories.  Write the corresponding CSS into your style.css and it will be applied to only to corresponding page. Don't know the HTML offhand (and we shouldn't have to look it up), but I've applied different CSS a bunch for different products/cats.

Comment: right, so there's your answer. whatever the product cat is, it should be a body class therefore enough for you to style accordingly in `style.css`.

Comment: i find a php function to style the product class in body class, but in my theme "enfold", the istruction to arrive from the body to my element is very very long

Comment: I'm going to flag this question as a duplicate as there's another answered question that solves this. This will require getting into the CSS, however long it is to override (which shouldn't be much).

Comment: Three line of css code, but now i think that is a theme problem..anyway thanks